# SQL Server how read a record and then write if it is not there without creating duplicates

Tags: multithreading, t-sql, sql-server-2005, jdbc

What are the better techniques for inserting a record into a table if it is not there already?

The issue is that the code checks if the record with the criteria exists, and if it does not, it creates one. However, a second thread could come along and check at the same time.

We started experimenting with TABLOCKX which initially worked, although it felt a bit like using an elephant gun, but we are also looking at using snapshot isolation, and it doesn't work in that context, where the second transaction can just come along and read the table.

This is a common problem, so it seems like there should be a more standard solution. Note that a unique index is not appropriate here, since the fields being searched can contain nulls, and SQL Server 2005 doesn't support a unique constraint in that context.

Comment: If you would be using SQL Server 2008, then you could also look at [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see anything in the original question about updating the table, so maybe you just want something like:

```
INSERT mytable (c1, c2, c3)
SELECT v1, v2, v3
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE c1=v1 AND c2=v2 AND c3=v3)
```

Comment: Thanks, definitely a solution, although I will have to see how real world it is. Theoretically a second thread and connection could do something in-between the where not exists lookup and the insert. I'm not sure SQL Server prevents that?

Comment: You're right that it isn't guaranteed to prevent duplicate inserts.  I'll change the answer to include WITH (UPDLOCK) in the subquery.  Also, even if you're not interested in updates, you can use the MERGE statement, have a match condition of 1=0, and just a WHEN NOT MATCHED section, and it will handle the concurrency correctly without a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Well inside of SQL 2008, I'd suggest using Merge; however, you tagged 2005.  So with MS SQL 2005, your best bet is to use a transaction:

I'd use something like this:

```
begin tran
   update table with (x) set ...
   where key = @key

   if @@rowcount = 0
   begin
          insert table (key, ...) values (@key,..)
   end
commit tran
```